# Kibana: how to display values aggregation in a visualization?

Tags: kibana

I send to logstash the amount of cores used on my cluster. I want to create a pie chart on Kibana that displays the number of cores used in the last 24 hours, but aggregate the values - i.e. display the values as 0-10 cores, 10-20 etc. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kibana choose visualisation then choose pie chart then choose range in the aggregation dropdown